# Can one pipe compound commands?

Tags: shell, pipe, xargs

My question is: can/how does one pipe [compound commands (`{ list; }`)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)? See Exhibit B. Exhibit A given for comparison's sake.

Exhibit A:

```
$ cat << EOF | xargs -n 1 echo           
foo
bar
qux
EOF
foo
bar
qux
```

Exhibit B:

```
$ cat << EOF | xargs -n 1 sh -c '{ var="$1"; echo "$var"; }'
foo
bar
qux
EOF
```

`man sh`:

```
-c               Read commands from the command_string operand
                            instead of from the standard input.  Special parame‐
                            ter 0 will be set from the command_name operand and
                            the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from
                            the remaining argument operands.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `sh -c "something"` needs another argument to become `$0`.

Your second example doesn't provide one, so the `$1` is an empty string and you get your 3 blank lines.
Use

```
cat << EOF | xargs -n 1 sh -c '{ var="$1"; echo "$var"; }' inlineshellscript
foo
bar
qux
EOF
food
bar
qux
```

In the script `$0` is `inlineshellscript`. Normally I would use `sh` rather than `inlineshellscript`.

Comment: Or even simpler replace `$1` by `$0`? Is there not a more elegant way to do this altogether?

Comment: @Erwann Do not replace `$1` by `$0`. `$0` has its purpose. See "pitfalls of treating `$0` like `$1`" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1526230/432690).

Comment: Or this, no? `cat << EOF | xargs -I {} sh -c '{ var={}; echo "$var"; }'`

Comment: @Erwann That solution is not great if there are "interesting" characters flowing down the pipe. There are not in this case of course, but in general it is best to let xargs split things rather than passing the characters to sh for it to interpret.

Comment: Would it not be better with `$SHELL` rather than `sh`, for consistency's sake? Also, `sh` is prone to "bad substitution".